# How do you include specific libraries based on the OS in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to modify a project that was initially only for Linux systems to compile and run on Windows. Syntactically, my code is correct. I am using CMake to make my build, and thus have a CMakeLists.txt file. There is a library I only want to link on Windows, but I am not sure of how to do that.

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(
   LIB1
   LIB2
   LIB3
)
```

I want this list to contain all of the libraries that currently reside in it, while also adding the windows specific library if we are building on a windows system. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Have a second `target_link_libraries(LIB1 ...)` statement behind an `if` test.

Comment: You could also fill a cmake list variable with the names of targets to link, `set(LIBS LIB2 LIB3) if (UNIX) list(APPEND LIBS pthread) elseif(WIN32) list(APPEND LIBS someWindowsLib) endif() target_link_libraries(LIB1 PRIVATE ${LIBS})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) to do this inline:

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGET}
    common_target
    $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID>:MSVC>:msvc_only_target>
    $<$<PLATFORM_ID:Linux>:linux_only_target>
)
```

Or, use the `if()` command:

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} common_target)
if(WIN32)
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET} windows_only_target)
endif()
```

Comment: The second version is definetly easier to read, especially if multiple libs are added this way.